# Expanding %userprofile% within a Set Variable within an if Statement. Batch

Tags: batch-file, variables, if-statement, set, expansion

I have something similar to the following...

```
set /p dir=Specify Path:
 if exist %dir% (
 echo ok
 ) else(
 echo not ok
)
```

If the user enters a path or variable like %userprofile%

when %dir% is used %userprofile% is not expanded within.

for example

```
set dir=%userprofile%
echo %dir% :: this does not expand
call echo %dir% :: this does expand
cd %dir% :: does not expand
call cd %dir% :: expands
```

but how would I have the path expand within a if statement.

Been banging my head on this one and i'm not really understanding DelayedExpansion.

Thanks.

Comment: After your `SET /P` command do this: `CALL set "dir=%dir%"`

Comment: I think i've got my head around delayed expansion which seems to allow changes to a Variable to be read before the statement has ended, if this is correct i don't think that really helps in my situation which is probably why i'm getting so confused as ive tried all combinations of ! & % without an luck. If /f %%a in (`echo %%dir%%`) do echo %a i believe expands also but that doesn't seem to help me either.:(

Comment: Thanks Squashman almost seems obvious now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user enters an environmental variable as the path you can easily expand that variable by using the CALL command.  So your code will look like this.

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p "dir=Specify Path:"

CALL set "dir=%dir%"

if exist "%dir%" (
    echo ok
) else (
    echo not ok
)
```